Moving after copying in assignment of conditional operator result
Simplified program as follows
struct S {
    S() {}
    S(const S &) {}
    S(S &&) = delete;
};

S x;
S y = false ? S() : x;

is accepted just fine by GCC and Clang, but the latest Visual Studio 2022 v17.10 rejects it with the error:
error C2280: 'S::S(S &&)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xnc7x6W4v
It appears that MSVC first copies the value of x in a temporary and then moves the temporary into y, unlike other compilers, which do not call S(S &&).
Is the behavior of Microsoft compiler correct according to C++ standard?

Interesting thing is that this MSVC bug is triggered only when the move constructor is explicitly deleted. If you want to fix this problem, don't declare S(S &&) = delete;, the default move constructor is already suppressed (not created). Report it to Microsoft, they usually fix simple bugs quickly.

@Gene There is a difference between the move constructor being deleted and not being declared at all. It is expected that the former will be ill-formed if the move constructor can be chosen, while the latter will fall back to the copy constructor.

If move constructor is not deleted then MSVC will perform copying twice: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7WKfvqoGW

@user17732522 -- there is a subtle difference between being explicitly deleted and not being implicitly default generated by compiler. But the result is the same, there is no move constructor available, and compiler will have to use copy constructor in both cases. If you think there is a case when declaring already suppressed default move ctor explicitly deleted makes the program ill-formed I want to see that.

@Gene That's very much possible and also the intention behind = delete. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/r7nn6xvGv. If you remove the move constructor declaration, then there won't be any move constructor declared at all and it will compile. A function defined as deleted still participates in overload resolution as normal, rather than not participating as a non-existent function would.

@Fedor -- it's copy elision

@user17732522 -- but this is totally different, you explicitly demand deleted function. But we were always talking about implicit conversions.

@Gene How is it different? S t = std::move(s); is copy-initialization, which will also use an implicit conversion to the type being initialized. The overload resolution used in forming the user-defined conversion sequence resolves to the move constructor if and only if it is declared. The overload resolution is ill-formed if the chosen constructor is deleted, i.e. if the move constructor is defined as deleted. Also, in the question by OP no implicit conversion will happen as I commented under one of the answers.

@Gene Correction: In S t = std::move(s); there is also no implicit conversion. Instead overload resolution on constructors is done immediately per https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-16.6.2.

@Gene • But the result is the same, there is no move constructor available... That is incorrect; the difference is that a deleted move constructor is available for being best match selected.  That subtle difference is a critical difference.

@Eljay -- it's not the case of function overload we are having here, so it's irrelevant.

MSVC is wrong; GCC and Clang are correct.
MSVC incorrectly applies the temporary materialization conversion (i.e. turning S() into an xvalue).
Looking at false ? S() : x;, this is a conditional operator where both possible expressions are of the same class type, but S() is a prvalue and x is an lvalue.
Therefore, the result is a prvalue ([expr.cond] p6).
Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to x ([expr.cond] p7), and the declaration of y is effectively:
S y = false ? S() : S(x);

The relevant bullet is [expr.cond] p7.1.

The second and third operands have the same type; the result is of that type and the result object is initialized using the selected operand.

Since C++17, the move constructor is never called here; instead, [dcl.init.general] p16.6.1 applies:

If the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the destination object.

S(x) is used to initialize the destination object y. The move constructor is never called, and temporary materialization does not take place.

[expr.cond]/4 says "if the second and third operand have different types". That's not the case here.

@user17732522 thanks, you're right. I've fixed it. Thankfully the conclusion is still the same; the result is a prvalue and MSVC is wrong.

Yes, although I wonder whether this is a defect in the standard, because it implies that constexpr S y = false ? S() : S(x); would be ill-formed per https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.9.

@user17732522 hmm yeah, it does seem a little bit defective because S(x) when done directly would just call the copy constructor which is no problem for empty classes, but when done through lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, this isn't allowed. Perhaps the defect lies with [expr.const].

@user17732522 https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/550

There are also class type lvalue-to-rvalue conversions in reinterpret_cast and const_cast. In the latter case that is a problem with constant expressions as well. Aside from that there are also class type lvalue-to-rvalue conversions in variadic function call and for volatile-qualified discarded-value expressions. In these cases constant expressions are not an issue.

But in general it seems to me that the wording is careful to avoid lvalue-to-rvalue conversions on class types. Lvalue-to-rvalue conversions are also used in https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.attr.depend-1 with a meaning that seems to assume scalar types. It seems to me like they shouldn't apply to class types.

The program is well-formed and msvc is wrong in rejecting the program. First note that S y = false ? S() : x; is copy initialization. Moreover the result of the ternary operator is a prvalue here.
Now the result of the ternary operator here is a prvalue. This can be seen from conditional operator:

The type and value category of the conditional expression E1 ? E2 : E3 are determined according to the following rules:



Otherwise, the result is a prvalue. If E2 and E3 do not have the same type, and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, overload resolution is performed using the built-in candidates below to attempt to convert the operands to built-in types. If the overload resolution fails, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, the selected conversions are applied and the converted operands are used in place of the original operands for step 6.




Next, from c++17 onwards, there is mandatory copy elision that is applicable here because the we've a prvalue from above.
From copy elision:

Since C++17, a prvalue is not materialized until needed, and then it is constructed directly into the storage of its final destination. This sometimes means that even when the language syntax visually suggests a copy/move (e.g. copy initialization), no copy/move is performed — which means the type need not have an accessible copy/move constructor at all. Examples include:

In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type.


(emphasis mine)
